# CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. Open JDK Error

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U281n.png)

st 16,
or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.unity3d.ads" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
]
stdout[

> Configure project :
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.2f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\28.0.3\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.2f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.2f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-28\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.2f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.2f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\28.0.3\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.2f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.2f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-28\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.2f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:checkReleaseManifest
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseSources
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE

> Task :processReleaseManifest FAILED

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
20 actionable tasks: 10 executed, 10 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <67e4f96bbb8d486db6550813353bb5eb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <67e4f96bbb8d486db6550813353bb5eb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <67e4f96bbb8d486db6550813353bb5eb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <67e4f96bbb8d486db6550813353bb5eb>:0) UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <67e4f96bbb8d486db6550813353bb5eb>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <67e4f96bbb8d486db6550813353bb5eb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <67e4f96bbb8d486db6550813353bb5eb>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <67e4f96bbb8d486db6550813353bb5eb>:0)

Answer (score 0):

change your build.gradle :
defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 19
}